# External drive hangs at MountingFilesystem then disappears from Disks

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have a Linux hard drive with some data I am trying to save.
I have mounted it inside of an external drive enclosure and connected it to a machine running Ubuntu 23.04.
The drive is recognized and all of the partitions show in Disks temporarily but it hangs at MountingFilesystem for a long time and then disappears from Disks.

I do not know much about Linux and I am not sure if the drive could be damaged or if it is something that is just not configured properly.

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You've not indicated if you're asking about Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop, Ubuntu 23.04 Server, or a *flavor* etc. I'd explore system logs for clues, especially errors relating to the `mount`.  You could have provided the `mount` command you used (*you didn't specify if server thus command, or desktop thus gui or command!*) as messages often show where commands are used. You also didn't provide any *file-system* details (*those details are related to the system where the drive came from!*) FYI: If you used a GUI tool to `mount`, using a terminal can show the details more easily than need to search logs

Answer (score 0):

You could try running SMART from the Disks application. This should provide some information on the status of the drive.
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html.en

Also check to make sure the enclosure your using is rated for the hard drive. 3.5 in hard drives require addition power so there should be a wall plug in addition to connecting it to your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
The drive is in a properly powered enclosure. 
I can’t run SMART from the Disks application since the drive disappears from the Disks application

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).